# How to debug JavaScript errors happening in google jsapi visualization corechart itself?

Tags: google-visualization

How do I load non-compressed/debug google jsapi libraries so I can effectively carry out DOM-level debugging in a browser. In particular: visualization corechart.

Here is how I load the jsapi:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
...
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm just not hip enough on technology to understand your question, but whenever I use Google Visualization, 100% of the stuff that comes out is accessible in an uncompressed version in the DOM (it can be accessed with firebug, etc.). What problem are you running in to that you need the uncompressed libraries? As is, this question is virtually impossible to answer.

Comment: I wish that were the case here. What I get is not realistically readable: function(a,b){var c=this.t(b),e=b&&null!=b.callback;if(e)var f=new W(b.callback); ... on a few very long lines. But since it is not all on a single line, perhaps that is indeed the long/debug form? I'd prefer a requestId to at least be named Id and not Bk... :-)

Comment: The internal code of Google's API is not human readable, but the input and output objects are (what happens in between is essentially a black box). What do you need to know the internal API calls for specifically? The input/output results aren't enough?

Comment: I wish they were, but I have a CORS situation where my code disappears in to the google libs and never returns -- exception in the lib. I can't pin it down without seeing what the google lib thinks is wrong... See this post: https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1242 Thanks!